# Session destroyed after redirect on payment gateway

Tags: php, session, payment-gateway

I have created an eCommerce website using the PHP MVC framework. For payment processing, I have integrated the PhonePe Payment Gateway API. I am facing an issue with session management after the user completes the payment process and returns to my website. Prior to the payment process, my website's session is working fine, but after the user returned, the session is getting destroyed.

To overcome this issue, I have implemented a solution where I store the user session in the database to prevent session loss. However, even after retrieving the session values from the database and assigning them to the session, the user is getting logged out.

I would appreciate your guidance on how to restore the user session from the database and prevent the logout issue.

Comment: Why do people always dislike finding the cause of problems, and try to choose a new method? How is the session destroyed?

Comment: I don't know but after redirection on the payment gateway site and coming back my session not working. Other than that my session is working as expected.

Comment: Go check the `SameSite` setting of your session cookie first of all.

Comment: Which PHP framework did you use to implement this payment gateway? If it is in Laravel go to `config/session.php` file and replace the `'same_site' => 'lax'` to `'same_site' => 'none'` would solve your problem